# How to assign more memory to Netbeans?

Tags: memory, netbeans

I have 24 GB of RAM on my PC, but sometimes when Netbeans compiles my projects, it says not enough memory to compile it, I looked at the memory useage, it shows : 586/590 M.

So how to tell Netbeans, there are plenty of RAM, use as much as you need ?

Comment: +1 use as much as you need? I have this conversation with netbeans everyday. It's an endless battle.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In the **etc** directory under your Netbeans-Home, edit the file **netbeans.conf** file.
**-Xms** and **-Xmx** should be increased to the values that allow your program to compile.

Here are the instructions in **netbeans.conf**:

```
# Note that default -Xmx and -XX:MaxPermSize are selected for you automatically.
# You can find these values in var/log/messages.log file in your userdir.
# The automatically selected value can be overridden by specifying -J-Xmx or
# -J-XX:MaxPermSize= here or on the command line.
```

Put the values in the **netbeans_default_options** string. Here is mine (remove linebreaks, added for readability):

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m 
-J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true 
-J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true 
-J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true  -J-Dsun.awt.disableMixing=true 
-J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd --laf Nimbus"
```

**EDIT:** `-J-Xms` sets the minimum Java heap size, `-J-Xmx` sets the maximum Java heap size.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. It would be nice to be able to set this from Netbeans' GUI, like Options -> Setting ...

Comment: What about real GUI programmers? Do they use GUIs? :-)

Comment: A local version of this file can be created unter `~/.netbeans/<version>/etc/netbeans.conf`, the `etc` dir has to be created manually.

Comment: @Mike.R The run option from the GUI only changes it for your application.  For netbeans itself you need to adjust the configuration file.

Comment: Note that with Java 8, the PermSize parameter is no longer needed.  It will be ignored.