# Netbeans runs out of memory after opening many projects

Tags: netbeans

I created a projects group for maven projects. Maven being able to build subprojects, there actually are dozens and dozens of sub-subprojects.

Now I have 405 projects open on Netbeans and I cannot use it anymore because when I start it, the system runs indefinitely trying to perform "opening projects" and eventually running out of memory when it goes in the build phase.

I'd like to start Netbeans again without all those 400+ projects. How to do so?

In case it's needed, I use Netbeans 7.4 on MS-Windows 7.

Edit: a now-deleted answer suggested me to close individually each project. This is not possible as the "close project" action is queued for after the build.

Comment: You could always [**allocate more memory for Netbeans**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18992956/2587435)

Comment: That's not an option, but thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to delete the netbeans folders one by one and succeeded quite early. What I did was delete the whole `%APPDATA%\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4\config\Preferences` folder, though the precise information of the opened project at startup seems to lie in `%APPDATA%\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui.properties`.