# Netbeans: MB Memory Usage Indicator

Tags: php, netbeans

On netbeans, (7.3.1), I'm curious about the 'MB' thing ( the mega-bytes indicator) which constantly changes and display numbers such as "274.9/305.6MB" (or "155.3/305.6MB" and so on) at the top of the editor. I gather that it has to do with the current memory allocation but how do I make good use of it? What does that tell me?

What's also interesting is the fact that the 2nd number ( which is 305.6MB in the above example ) tends to be not changing.

Please shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first number represents amount of memory currently used by Netbeans (*that is why it changes all the time*) and the second number represents the amount of memory allocated to Netbeans (*maximum amount of memory Netbeans can use*).

Hint: Amount of memory allocated to Netbeans can be changed with [-Xms and -Xmx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18992956/1459926) parameters.

Answer (score 2):

First number is the amount of ram netbeans is using currently

second number is the total amount of ram that can be used by netbeans

You can increase the values by changing the -Xms and -Xmx parameters in netbeans.conf

**[More About -Xms and -Xmx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763095/3447241)**

Comment: Thank you Vamsi for your answer. Alex also has a similar answer. I do appreciate your link though... However, Alex must have beaten you in replying a faster answer. That's why I had to choose his answer as the accepted one even though I up'ped for answers. Thank you to both of you.

Comment: @AverageJoe: Am Happy that i was helpful :)