# How to set two options in VM ptions -Netbeans-Windows?

Tags: java, netbeans

i am facing java heap space error while compiling java files from Netbeans.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer.<init>(Buffer.java:59)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3437)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:488)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3131)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2299)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2722)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2788)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2738)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1617)
```

i alreadey set VM option for opencv as native library like this:

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\opencv\build\java\x86"
```

how can i set second option for java max heap size `-Xmx2048m` in VM option ?
or there is another approach to increase java heap size in netbeans?

Comment: You can refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992219/how-to-assign-more-memory-to-netbeans

Comment: Doesn't it support for multi-line input? press enter and then add `-Xmx2048m` on the next line

Comment: @m.yadav i edited my netbeans.conf file and added -J-Xms2048m but it doesn't work for me

Comment: @STaefi no it doesn't accept multi line options