# Netbeans 12.5 increase heap memory

Tags: memory, netbeans, heap-memory

I'm trying to open a large php project on netbeans 12.5.
Netbeans is installad as a snap module on ubuntu 18.04.

Every time I'm getting a heap memory limit exception and I see 8 cpu cores running to about 100%.

Is there a way to increase memory limit? Documentation I read refers to previous versions of netbeans and I can't change netbeans.conf under snap filesystem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign more memory to Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992219/how-to-assign-more-memory-to-netbeans)

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT

Like @skomisa said, If you can't modify `netbeans.config` file, you can launch it from console like this:- **`netbeans.exe -J-Xmx50m`**.
But its very hard to do it every time you start netbeans. So for that follow these steps:-

- First go to the folder where you have your NetBeans shortcut.(In Start Menu Folder or Desktop).
- Then right click the shortcut and in the target section, add **-J-Xmx50m**.

See this image.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image 2]

## Original Answer

Open your netbeans installation and go to etc folder. Then open netbeans.conf file.
Then search for `netbeans_default_options` string. If you want 50 heap size then add the `-J-Xmx50m` to that string. If it is already present change the value of it.
My file is like this:-
(Removed comments)

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-XX:+UseStringDeduplication -J-Xss2m -J-Xmx50m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dplugin.manager.check.updates=false -J-Dnetbeans.extbrowser.manual_chrome_plugin_install=yes -J--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-modules=jdk.jshell -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED  -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.classfile=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.javap=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.X11=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.synth=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED  -J-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions"

# Default location of JDK:
# (set by installer or commented out if launcher should decide)
#
# It can be overridden on command line by using --jdkhome <dir>
# Be careful when changing jdkhome.
# There are two NetBeans launchers for Windows (32-bit and 64-bit) and
# installer points to one of those in the NetBeans application shortcut 
# based on the Java version selected at installation time.
#
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1"

# Additional module clusters:
# using ${path.separator} (';' on Windows or ':' on Unix):
#
#netbeans_extraclusters="/absolute/path/to/cluster1:/absolute/path/to/cluster2"
```

Comment: I can't modify netbeans.conf file under snap

Comment: @MatteoRossi why

Comment: @MatteoRossi Even if you can't edit **netbeans.conf**, you can still do what JFan suggests by passing the value as a startup parameter to NetBeans. For example, from the command line submit **netbeans.exe -J-Xmx50m** to pass the JVM option **-Xmx50m** to the JVM when starting NetBeans.

Comment: @skomisa You are right.

Comment: @JFan While your updated answer is good in principle, the specific argument you provided as an example (**-J-Xmx50m**) unfortunately results in an **OutOfMemoryError** which prevents NetBeans from starting. The JVM is trying to run NetBeans in 50 MB of memory, which is obviously not enough. Tweaking the value to **-J-Xmx50g** (i.e. max memory of 50 GB instead of 50 MB) works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can configure netbeans.conf with NetBeans 12.5 and newer Snap packages

```
mkdir -p ~/snap/netbeans/current/etc
cp /snap/netbeans/current/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf ~/snap/netbeans/current/etc/netbeans.conf
gedit ~/snap/netbeans/current/etc/netbeans.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

-J-Xmx50m worked fine for me with NetBeans 16
Thanks a lot, I really didn't what to do with it being so slow.
I was ready to ditch netbeans, which I really used to like back in the days.

Thanks again