# NetBeans boot optimization?

Tags: performance, netbeans

My main computer is my Windows Surface with only 4GB of RAM-yikes! So IDEs like NetBeans take a long time to load. Is there a way I can configure this IDE to boot faster?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/229763/6221024

Comment: @DillonDavis Thanks for the link! I saw that in essence reducing the number of projects opened at startup will help, as will disabling plugins. Problem for me is, I'm running without any plugins and maybe only two or three projects at a time. I didn't see anything specific about actual settings configuration, sadly. Any ideas?